# Google Maps Directions API Javascript Error undefined null d.defaultview or evaluating a.firstChild

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova App using Google Maps Javascript Directions API.
The Cordova google maps plugin does not support the Directions API, so Javascript is my last resort, to get the feature working.

I have tried it already with v=3, v=3.exp, and without any v soever, but no result.

Also, it does not make any difference, whether I include the script with an iOS, Android or Web-API Key, no change.

I took the demo from Google's developer documentation, all is working perfectly on Web, but not in my Cordova App with javascript :(

The Javascript included from googlemaps.com crashes with:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.defaultView')in common.js 3140:
                    if (d.defaultView && d.defaultView.getComputedStyle && (d = d.defaultView.getComputedStyle(c, null))) {
                d = d.position || d.getPropertyValue("position") || "";
                break a
            }
```

This code is working flawlessly on web but not in a Cordova app:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height:500px;"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {
                lat: 48.2265,
                lng: 12.6758
            }
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsService.route({
            origin: 'Berlin, Germany',
            destination: 'Vienna, Austria',
            travelMode: 'WALKING',
            waypoints: [{
                location: {
                    lat: 51.339696,
                    lng: 12.373075
                },
                stopover: true
            }, {
                location: {
                    lat: 50.075538,
                    lng: 14.4378
                },
                stopover: true
            }, {
                location: {
                    lat: 48.30694,
                    lng: 14.28583
                },
                stopover: true
            }]
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggesting using cordova-plugin-googlemaps to display the native maps and the JS SDK for the directions service to retrieve directions. That way you get natively smooth maps and can draw on the route manually using polylines and markers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977467/777265

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback. But I was able to fix that bug myself, it was a timing problem while loading and executing the initMap callback